# Excel 2016 TEXT function ignores formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016, text-formatting

I have a small pivot table displaying the total sales of three brands in two columns (one as currency, the other as % of total). The currency column's numbers are formatted as currency, with thousands separator, two decimal places and "лв." after each number. For each of these rows, I have created a dynamic 'label' which I have copied onto a pie chart so I have custom data values. One label reads as such:

```
=A4&CHAR(10)&TEXT(GETPIVOTDATA("Sales";$A$3;"Brand";A4);"#'### лв."&CHAR(10)&TEXT(GETPIVOTDATA("Sales %";$A$3;"Brand";A4);"0.00%"))
```

The issue I am having is that the text function seems to ignore the "#'###.## лв." formatting completely. Instead of displaying "1'234'567.89 лв.", the function displays "123'456'789 лв.", misplacing the thousands separator, ignoring the decimal comma, and making the number seem greater that it is. The percentages are formatted correctly. Any help with this issue would be very appreciated!

Comment: had you tried to change the "#'### лв." to "#'###.## лв."  ?

Answer (score 0):

=A4&CHAR(10)&TEXT(GETPIVOTDATA("Sales";$A$3;"Brand";A4);"#'### лв."&CHAR(10)&TEXT(GETPIVOTDATA("Sales %";$A$3;"Brand";A4);"0.00%"))

By moving the last bracket from the code above to right after the formatting and before the & sign, the issue was fixed.

=A4&CHAR(10)&TEXT(GETPIVOTDATA("Sales";$A$3;"Brand";A4);"#'### лв.")&CHAR(10)&TEXT(GETPIVOTDATA("Sales %";$A$3;"Brand";A4);"0.00%")